# css image filters - browser compatibility

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I'm looking for a smooth solution to implement a filter (blur + opacity) to images - working on the most popular browsers (sadly, IE counts as well!), and my code isn't working properly:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(3px) opacity(40%);
-moz-filter: blur(3px) opacity(40%);
-o-filter: blur(3px) opacity(40%);
-ms-filter: blur(3px) opacity(40%);
filter: blur(3px) opacity(40%);
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

I need an alternative to svg markup, too much to adjust:

```
<svg>
  <image ... />
  <filter id="test">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3"/>
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0.8"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</svg>

.tile:hover image{ filter:url(#test); }
```

There has to be an easier solution than this, adjusting my markup to work with svg is too much work.

a demo of the gallery I'm building can be viewed [here](http://www.pajalunga.ch/test/fp_content)

Thanks in advance for your help or hints!

Comment: IE only supports SVG filters and only on SVG content. There's no other alternative unless your gallery consists of static raster images in which case you could blur them in something like photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS filter is 175 characters. The SVG markup is 195 characters. If you want IE support, you have to use SVG. It's not that bad.